# HTTP4Component Proxy + SSL erro na requisição ao serviço externo

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy

Fala turma,
Estou utilizando o Apache Camel em meu projeto para fazer uma integração.
A principio estava fazendo uma conexão com um serviço externo com certificado, funcionando localmente, ao implantar no servidor houve a necessidade de adicionar o ip do servidor proxy. Com isso o camel parece que não pega mais a configuração do certificado, procurei algo para o funcionamento dos dois e não encontrei.
Preciso de um auxilio para o funcionamento dos dois.

Configuração do certificado:

```
    protected void configureSslForHttp4()
    {
        KeyStoreParameters trust_ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        trust_ksp.setResource(config.getKeyStore());
        trust_ksp.setPassword(config.getKeyStorePassword());

        KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
        kmp.setKeyStore(trust_ksp);
        kmp.setKeyPassword(config.getKeyStorePassword());

        SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
        scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

        HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
        httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);

    }
```

Configuração para adicionar o proxy:

- ProxyHost = 172.0.0.1
- ProxyPort: 8085

```
getContext().getGlobalOptions().put("http.proxyHost", config.getProxyHost());
getContext().getGlobalOptions().put("http.proxyPort", config.getProxyPort());
```

Ao executar é exibido o log:

```
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 20][route: {tls}->https://172.0.0.1:8085->https://servicosexterno.com.br:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 200]
o.a.c.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-1771a9a38dc3-1593470960512-0-47 on ExchangeId: ID-1771a9a38dc3-1593470960512-0-46). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
o.a.c.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-1771a9a38dc3-1593470960512-0-47 on ExchangeId: ID-1771a9a38dc3-1593470960512-0-46). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake


javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:994)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:334)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:193)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:715)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:638)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:248)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:76)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta, para que seja passado o contexto já configurado no http4 deve ser enviado para o proxy também, da seguinte forma:

> proxyAuthScheme (proxy) | Proxy authentication scheme to use. The value can be one of: http, https

Então o meu link ficou da seguinte forma:

- https4://servicosexterno.com.br:443?proxyAuthScheme=http4

Aqui está [o link](https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Using-the-HTTP4-component-to-make-a-HTTPS-call-behind-proxy-sever-td5719105.html#a5719162) da fonte onde encontrei a resposta.